# Embedded blazegraph vs orientdb?

Tags: orientdb, graph-databases, blazegraph

We are looking for a embedded graph database that can run withing application scope. I have tried a proof of concept with OrientDB and blazegraph by integrating jar files within application. I'm not sure which one to pick for my application.
Can anybody explain me which is better among these two?

Comment: You should clarify your requirements and concerns. Also some research you've made so far. Otherwise the question is too broad, undefined and opinion-based.

Answer (score 1):

(disclaimer: I was part of the OrientDB team)

The first thing I evaluate is the licence model. 
OrientDB is released under ASL while Blazegraph is released under GPLv2.
Can you deal with GPLv2?

Moreover, the blazegraph github repo is not updated since the end of 2016.
OrientDB, AFAIK, is going to release the 3.0 version and 2.2.x should be very stable, it's at 2.2.30 right now.

After that, you can start to evaluate the features
- APIs
- query languages: SQL, gremlin, RDF 
- db features: kind on indexes, backup, restore
- addons: console, web interfaces
- client support (java, js, phyton etc.)

Even if you want to go embedded, maybe in the future you will need to deploy your db in standalone way, so I will evaluate compatibility and support of other client languages.